# firstorDefault performance rising

Tags: c#, linq, performance, dictionary

part of the code:

```
Dictionary<Calculation, List<PropertyValue>> result = new Dictionary<Calculation, List<PropertyValue>>();
while (reader != null && reader.Read()) //it loops about 60000, and it will be bigger
{
    #region create calc and propvalue variables
    //...
    #endregion

    //this FirstOrDefault needs a lot of time
    tmpElementOfResult = result.Keys.FirstOrDefault(r => r.InnerID == calc.InnerID);
    if (tmpElementOfResult == null)
    {
        result.Add(calc, new List<PropertyValue> { propValue });
    }
    else
    {
        result[tmpElementOfResult].Add(propValue);
    }
}
```

Could you give me some idea how to make it faster, because now it's approximately 25 sec :( ?

Comment: Put the reader != null comparation outside of the while clause. Now you are checking it about 60000... when you could check it once.

Comment: Yeah I fix it, it's a mistake :) . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should have a dictionary from the type of `calc.InnerID`, instead of a `Dictionary<Calc, ...>`. That way you can do the lookup far more quickly. Do you actually need to store the `Calc` itself at all, or are you only interested in the ID?

For example:

```
Dictionary<Guid, List<PropertyValue>> result = 
    new Dictionary<Guid, List<PropertyValue>>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Work out calc
    List<PropertyValue> list;
    if (!result.TryGetValue(calc.InnerID, out list))
    {
         list = new List<PropertyValue>();
         result[calc.InnerID] = list;
    }
    list.Add(propValue);
}
```

Alternatively, if you can convert the reader to an `IEnumerable<Calc>` you could use:

```
Lookup<Guid, PropertyValue> result = items.ToLookup(x => x.InnerID,
                                                    // Or however you get it...
                                                    x => x.PropertyValue);
```

EDIT: It sounds like two Calc values should be deemed equal if they have the same `InnerID`, right? So override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` within `Calc` to refer to the `InnerID`. Then you can just use:

```
Lookup<Calc, PropertyValue> result = items.ToLookup(x => x,
                                                    // Or however you get it...
                                                    x => x.PropertyValue);
```

... or you can use code like the first snippet, but with a `Dictionary<Calc, ...>`:

```
Dictionary<Calc, List<PropertyValue>> result = 
    new Dictionary<Calc, List<PropertyValue>>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    // Work out calc
    List<PropertyValue> list;
    if (!result.TryGetValue(calc, out list))
    {
         list = new List<PropertyValue>();
         result[calc] = list;
    }
    list.Add(propValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's far more quickly to store only the innerID, but I need the whole calc later :( .

Thanks for the answer it's useful! Could you give my new answer a look?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Finally, I solved it not to use the whole calc, so I use the first version of your answer :) .

Won't it be slow if I just override the equal, and use the whole calc again? Isn't it almost the same solution like my original:

result.Keys.FirstOrDefault(r => r.InnerID == calc.InnerID); ?

Comment: @Zoltan: No, it's not the same solution at all. Using FirstOrDefault performs a linear scan of all the keys. Using the normal dictionary methods will be *much* quicker because it'll use the fact that it's a hash table.

Comment: I thought that it uses at least logarithmic scan, but you're right hashing is much quicker! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
  tmpElementOfResult = result.Keys.FirstOrDefault(r => r.InnerID == calc.InnerID);
```

use

```
  result.ContainsKey(calc.InnerId);
```

to check if a key is present.

Comment: That's not going to work without changing the type of `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
                lookUpForResult = result.ToLookup(x => x.Key.InnerID, x => x.Value);

                if (lookUpForResult.Contains(calc.InnerID))
                {
                    result.Add(calc, new List<PropertyValue> { propValue });
                }
                else
                {
                   (lookUpForResult[calc.InnerID]).Add(propValue);
                }
```

Comment: The point of the lookup is that it does all of that for you. You don't need to add the values yourself. This should also be an edit to your question... it's not an *answer* to your question.

Comment: I can't reach the List<PropertyValue> from the LookUp :( .

Comment: I solved it not to use the whole calculation. Thanks for the answers!